# Trap Subroutine LC3 Assembly

Tags: assembly, subroutine, low-level, lc3

Hi I have a problem for a cs class

```
       The puts TRAP routine has been disabled for some reason. Write an LC-3 
      subroutine called puts that
  implements its behaviour. In other words when the subroutine is called 
 register R0 will contain the
 address of a null-delimited string and the subroutine will simply print the 
string and return. You will of
course need to utilize the TRAP routine out that prints a character.
```

do 
  NOT have to write a main
  program.

So my approach to this was this I'm not sure if this is correct or if my logic is right

```
    PUTS:      
    ADD R2, R0, #0;
    AND R0, R0, #0;
    ADD R0, R2, #0;

    Out(trapx21) ; print first char in r0;


    BRp PUTS ; repeat loop
```

I'm not sure if i'm doing this correctly any help?

Comment: the putChar usually takes the char value directly, i.e. `r0` should then contain the ASCII value, but `puts` takes pointer to char, i.e. `r0` contains memory address. So you will have to copy pointer to other register, keep loading chars from the pointer into `r0` and do putChar, and loop not infinitely, but only until nul terminator of string is hit. (I don't know LC3, nor it's trap API, so verify my assumptions against your docs, this is just general advice how it usually works on other platforms) .. you current state is like "15% done and slightly off", but looks like a good start.

Comment: what about now I made some changes? @Ped7g

Comment: If you have some kind of emulator/simulator with debugger, that's the simplest way to learn assembly, to keep experimenting, and single stepping instructions in debugger, and watching what happens. As I wrote above, I don't know LC3. What you edited is surely not correct, doesn't resemble any memory load, or pointer update, etc, looks like random text from you (you went like from 15% to 10% done, and +30% junk added). Don't guess, think what you want from computer, then write that. And debug.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things off about your TRAP.

1. The biggest mistake, you are making use of the OUT trap within your trap service routine.  When traps are called the return address is put in R7.  When you make a call to the OUT trap, R7 is clobbered  Now you have no way of getting back to whatever code called the trap in the first place.
2. You will need a RET instruction at the end to get back to whoever called you
3. Your code is not actually getting the characters from the string that is contained in R0. So if you read from the address contained in R0 (via LDR) you should get the first character, read from address contained in R0+1 and you should get the second character, you have to continually read characters from the address in R0 until you receive a 0 which is the NUL terminator.

And contrary to the instructions in your problem, you should write a MAIN to test it.

Comment: Thank-you I appreciate it ill give it a shot with your recommendations